# Logging Custom DataImportHandler Transformer in SOLR

Tags: java, solr, log4j2, dataimporthandler

I have created a custom DataImportHandler transformer for use in indexing contents from both the data base and the file system into SOLR. I can kick off the data import. I can see in SOLR's log (and on the web administration console using the debug feature of the full-import call) where the transformer is called, but it's clearly not doing what I want and the import errors out. What I can't see is output from the transformer. I have tried System.out, System.err, and getting a log4j Logger expecting that SOLR's log settings will apply - they sure don't seem to and no matter what I do I see nothing in solr.log Do I need to create my own log4j 2 settings? If so, where do I put them on the classpath?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I also have some custom code in which I want to get some logging done but its not working for me. If you find anything please share

Comment: @Yatin - after using log4j2 and reloading the core, I see the logging output in the Admin console only. I can't find it in the SOLR log directory anywhere. It's...a partial solution?